# Mobile Web View for website

Tags: html, css, mobile-phones

After finalizing site, now finding out that main plugin won't work on any mobile device.  My bad.

Need to create a VERY basic CSS for mobile devices.  Any recommendations on a simple css stylesheet template/tutorial.  Saw jQtouch and Jquery Mobile and think this is an overkill for my needs.

Also, a reliable detection for when to hand out the mobile css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, you want css3 media queries: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries/

And a good framework is: http://mir.aculo.us/2010/10/28/zepto-js-a-jquery-compatible-mobile-javascript-framework-in-2k-presentation/

Comment: Took me a while to figure out, but WOW that was easy.  Ended up using jQuery Mobile.  THANK!